# Simple kivy app press button to play mp3 doesn't work on android device

Tags: android, python, audio, kivy, buildozer

I created a simple App. When pressed on a button to play a mp3 file. It works in terminal but when I compile it with buildozer and install on an android device only splash image appears and then app crashes and device returns to main screen.

```
kivy.require('1.8.0')

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader


class TTS(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__(orientation="vertical")
        self.add_widget(Label(text='[b]Una applicacion\n'
                                   'para aprender un poco [i]turco[/i][/b]',
                              halign='center', size_hint_y=.07, markup=True))
        self.create_w()

    def create_w(self):
        buton1 = Button(text="Merhaba\nHola",halign='center')
        buton1.bind(on_press=self.okubuton1)

        buton2 = Button(text="Nasılsın?\nCómo estás?",halign='center')
        buton2.bind(on_press=self.okubuton2)

        buton3 = Button(text="Nereye gidiyorsun?\n¿A dónde vas?",halign='center')
        buton3.bind(on_press=self.okubuton3)

        buton4 = Button(text="Nerelisin?\n¿De donde eres?",halign='center')
        buton4.bind(on_press=self.okubuton4)

        buton5 = Button(text="Kaç yaşındasın?\n¿Cuantos años tienes?",halign='center')
        buton5.bind(on_press=self.okubuton5)

        buton6 = Button(text="Çok güzelsin\nEres muy guapa",halign='center')
        buton6.bind(on_press=self.okubuton6)

        buton7 = Button(text="Çok yakışıklısın\nEres muy guapo",halign='center')
        buton7.bind(on_press=self.okubuton7)

        buton8 = Button(text="Türkçe biliyor musun?\n¿Hablas turco?",halign='center')
        buton8.bind(on_press=self.okubuton8)

        buton9 = Button(text="Bunun fiyatı ne kadar?\n¿Cuánto cuesta este?",halign='center')
        buton9.bind(on_press=self.okubuton9)

        buton10 = Button(text="Seni seviyorum\nTe amo",halign='center')
        buton10.bind(on_press=self.okubuton10)

        buton11 = Button(text="Gerizekalı\nImbécil",halign='center')
        buton11.bind(on_press=self.okubuton11)

        buton12 = Button(text="Salak\nIdiota",halign='center')
        buton12.bind(on_press=self.okubuton12)

        buton13  = Button(text="Acıktım\nTengo hambre",halign='center')
        buton13.bind(on_press=self.okubuton13)

        buton14 = Button(text="Susadım\nTengo sed",halign='center')
        buton14.bind(on_press=self.okubuton14)

        buton15 = Button(text="Hoşçakal\nAdiós",halign='center')
        buton15.bind(on_press=self.okubuton15)

        grid=GridLayout(cols=3)
        self.add_widget(grid)

        grid.add_widget(buton1)
        grid.add_widget(buton2)
        grid.add_widget(buton3)
        grid.add_widget(buton4)
        grid.add_widget(buton5)
        grid.add_widget(buton6)
        grid.add_widget(buton7)
        grid.add_widget(buton8)
        grid.add_widget(buton9)
        grid.add_widget(buton10)
        grid.add_widget(buton11)
        grid.add_widget(buton12)
        grid.add_widget(buton13)
        grid.add_widget(buton14)
        grid.add_widget(buton15)

    def okubuton1(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Merhaba.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton2(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Nasılsın.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton3(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Nereye_gidiyorsun.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton4(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Nerelisin.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton5(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Kaç_yaşındasın.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton6(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Çok_güzelsin.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton7(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Çok_yakışıklısın.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton8(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Türkçe_biliyor_musun.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton9(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Bunun_fiyatı_ne_kadar.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton10(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Seni_seviyorum.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton11(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Gerizekalı.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton12(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Salak.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton13(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Acıktım.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton14(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Susadım.mp3')
        sound.play()

    def okubuton15(self, obj):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('Hoşçakal.mp3')
        sound.play()



class AprendeTurco(App):
    def build(self):
        return TTS()

if __name__== "__main__":
    AprendeTurco().run()
```

What am I missing?

And my buildozer.spec file is:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = Aprende Turco v1

# (str) Package name
package.name = aprendeturcov1

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = com.ravnsaprendeturco

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,mp3

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png/*.mp3

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 1.0

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma seperated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
presplash.filename = /home/ravn/buildozer/iconn.png

# (str) Icon of the application
icon.filename = /home/ravn/buildozer/iconn.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 1

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = WAKE_LOCK


# (int) Android API to use
#android.api = 19

# (int) Minimum API required
android.minapi = 9

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 9c

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#android.p4a_dir =

# (list) python-for-android whitelist
#android.p4a_whitelist =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, if not master, useful to try
# not yet merged features.
#android.branch = master

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (list) Android additionnal libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

All the mp3 files and main.py are in the buildozer folder.
[Here is the logcat.](https://justpaste.it/yxj6)

Comment: ,,What am I missing?'' - a logcat report, obviously.

Comment: From logcat I see unsuccessful dllimports. Try to add `sqlite3` into requirements. Missing `_imaging.so` might be an old bug (update buildozer).

Comment: I updated buildozer, and added sqlite3 to requirements. But now buildozer can't even compile. There are many bugs I fixed but one I cannot:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 517, in <module>
    make_package(args)
  File "build.py", line 365, in make_package
    subprocess.check_call([ANT, arg])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ant', 'debug']' returned non-zero exit status 1

Comment: I fixed every bug after updating buildozer, one included above too. App crashes and "_imaging.so" error is the problem again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, `mp3` file makes app crashed on android device, if the app is made by kivy SoundLoader and compiled by Buildozer. Use `.wav` or `.ogg` file, instead.

Answer (score 0):

When my app crashed, I found a traceback saying `NoneType object has no attribute 'state'`. So I made sure there was an

```py
if <SOUND_FILE>:
    <SOUND_FILE>.play() # <SOUND_FILE>.state = 'play' | <SOUND_FILE>.stop()
```

whenever I wanted to change the state of the audio. Now I can **open** my app on an Android device and **use** it, but the audio won't play. That's what I'm trying to fix currently. I'm thinking the audio files are always `None`. So if you want to have `mp3` files in your `apk` **and** you want your app to not crash on an Android device, you can **try** what I did.