# Kivy sounds do not play on android device even though they play fine on laptop

Tags: python, kivy, logcat, kivy-language, buildozer

I am trying to play a sound using Kivy. The sound plays perfectly and everything works perfectly on my laptop, but when I load the APK on my Android device, the sound does not play.

I have manually allowed "storage permissions" on my android device, and in my buildozer.spec file I have included permissions to write and read external storage. I created a test file to try and debug to see what was going wrong but to no avail. I will share the details of this test file below.

To start, here is the .py file:

```py
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader

__version__ = '0.1'

class SoundTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('soundtest.kv')
        return SoundTestWidget()

class SoundTestWidget(Widget):
    def playsound(self):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('testmusic.wav')
        sound.play()

SoundTestApp().run()
```

Next, here is the .kv file:

```
<SoundTestWidget>:
    soundbutton: sound_button

    Button:
        id: sound_button
        size: (root.width,root.height)
        background_color: (1, 0, 0, 1)
        text: "press to play music"
        pos: self.pos
        on_release:
            self.text = "music is playing"
            root.playsound()
```

Next, here is the Buildozer.spec file:

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = SoundTest

# (str) Package name
package.name = soundtest

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.soundtest

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

Finally, here are some extracts from the logcat, which may or may not be relevant (I do not know yet how to properly read a logcat):

```
09-22 22:24:52.558  6029  1471 E pageboostd: orgsoundtestsoundtest, amt 0 scnt 0 fcnt 0
09-22 22:24:52.559  4865  5176 E ActivityTaskManager: TouchDown intent received, starting ActiveLaunch
09-22 22:24:52.560  4865  5176 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted:org.soundtest.soundtest user:0
09-22 22:24:52.560  4865  5176 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageWhitelisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
09-22 22:24:52.560  4865  5176 D ActivityManager: package  org.soundtest.soundtest, user - 0 is SDcard whitelisted
09-22 22:24:52.560  4865  5176 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:org.soundtest.soundtest user:0
09-22 22:24:52.560  4865  5176 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
09-22 22:24:52.561  4865  5176 I ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted:org.soundtest.soundtest user:0
09-22 22:24:52.561  4865  5176 D ApplicationPolicy: isApplicationExternalStorageBlacklisted: DO is not enabled on user 0. Allowed.
09-22 22:24:52.561  4865  5176 D ActivityTaskManager: starting Active launch

09-22 22:19:24.770  4865  5191 I Pageboost: active launch for : org.soundtest.soundtest , 1
09-22 22:19:24.772  4865  5176 E ActivityTaskManager: TouchDown intent received, starting ActiveLaunch
09-22 22:19:24.772  4865  5176 D ActivityTaskManager: starting Active launch
09-22 22:19:24.837  4865  6989 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 2314000  uid : 1000  pid : 4865  pkgName : APP_LAUNCH@CPU_MIN@7
09-22 22:19:24.837  5574  5574 D ActivityOptions: makeRemoteAnimation, adapter=android.view.RemoteAnimationAdapter@5d434e1, caller=com.android.systemui.shared.system.ActivityOptionsCompat.makeRemoteAnimation:68 com.android.launcher3.QuickstepAppTransitionManagerImpl.getActivityLaunchOptions:350 com.android.launcher3.Launcher.getActivityLaunchOptions:3071
09-22 22:19:24.840  4865  6997 I ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=org.soundtest.soundtest/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity bnds=[975,120][1156,451]} from uid 10073
09-22 22:19:24.841  6953  6953 E SDHMS:ib.qa: e = /sys/class/lcd/panel/vrr: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
09-22 22:19:24.846  4865  6997 D CustomFrequencyManagerService: acquireDVFSLockLocked : type : DVFS_MIN_LIMIT  frequency : 2314000  uid : 1000  pid : 4865  pkgName : AMS_APP_SWITCH@CPU_MIN@38
09-22 22:19:24.846  4865  6997 D ActivityManagerPerformance: AMP_acquire() APP_SWITCH
09-22 22:19:24.846  4865  6997 D ActivityTaskManager: MultiTaskingTaskLaunchParamsModifier:task=null display-from-source=0 display-id=0 display-windowing-mode=1
09-22 22:19:24.847  4865  6997 D ActivityTaskManager: MultiTaskingTaskLaunchParamsModifier:task=null display-from-source=0 display-id=0 display-windowing-mode=1 activity-options-fullscreen=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) non-freeform-display maximized-bounds
09-22 22:19:24.849  4865  6997 D ActivityTaskManager: MultiTaskingTaskLaunchParamsModifier:tid=340 display-from-task=0 display-id=0 display-windowing-mode=1 activity-options-fullscreen=Rect(0, 0 - 0, 0) non-freeform-display maximized-bounds
09-22 22:19:24.850  4865  6997 D ActivityTaskManager: updateMinimizedState: unknown notifyReason=2
09-22 22:19:24.855  4865  4906 D GameManagerService: MultiWindowEventListener.onFocusStackChanged(), state=0, top=ComponentInfo{org.soundtest.soundtest/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
09-22 22:19:24.855  4865  5173 D GameManagerService: handleForegroundChange(). pkgName: org.soundtest.soundtest, clsName: org.kivy.android.PythonActivity,FgActivityName:org.soundtest.soundtest/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity,userID:0
09-22 22:19:24.855  4865  5173 D GameManagerService:   handleForegroundChange(). set mFgApp: org.soundtest.soundtest
09-22 22:19:24.855  4865  5173 D GameManagerService: notifyResumePause(). pkg: org.soundtest.soundtest, type: 4, isMinimized: false, isTunableApp: false
09-22 22:19:24.856  4865  5173 D GameManagerService:   notifyResumePause(). do nothing. mKillNotiCount: 1
09-22 22:19:24.856  4865  4906 D GameSDKService: MultiWindowEventListener.onFocusStackChanged(), state=0, top=ComponentInfo{org.soundtest.soundtest/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
09-22 22:19:24.857  4865  4906 D GameSDKService: MultiWindowEventListener.onFocusStackChanged(): org.soundtest.soundtest
09-22 22:19:24.857  4865  4906 D MdnieScenarioControlService: MultiWindowState : false , mode : 0
09-22 22:19:24.858  4865  4865 I Pageboost: package org.soundtest.soundtest
09-22 22:19:24.859  4865  4865 I Pageboost: stop active launch
```

The app does not crash on Android. But the sound does not play. What is the problem?

**EDIT:**

Thanks to the answers below, we realized that the problem is likely that I needed to add the requirement ffpyplayer. However, there is an issue that buildozer refuses to build when I add this requirement. Here is the log:

```
[INFO]:    -> running configure --disable-everything --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree --enable-protocol=https,tls_op...(and 891 more)
Exception in thread background thread for pid 33867:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 917, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 865, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 1662, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2606, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 2304, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/configure --disable-everything --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree --enable-protocol=https,tls_openssl --enable-parser=aac,ac3,h261,h264,mpegaudio,mpeg4video,mpegvideo,vc1 --enable-decoder=aac,h264,mpeg4,mpegvideo --enable-muxer=h264,mov,mp4,mpeg2video --enable-demuxer=aac,h264,m4v,mov,mpegvideo,vc1 --disable-symver --disable-programs --disable-doc --enable-filter=aresample,resample,crop,adelay,volume,scale --enable-protocol=file,http,hls --enable-small --enable-hwaccels --enable-gpl --enable-pic --disable-static --disable-debug --enable-shared --target-os=android --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=armv7a-linux-androideabi21- --arch=arm --strip=arm-linux-androideabi-strip --sysroot=/Users/maithreyasitaraman/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --enable-neon --prefix=/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg

  STDOUT:
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1260, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 709, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 154, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 216, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/ffmpeg/__init__.py", line 135, in build_arch
    shprint(configure, *flags, _env=env)
  File "/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 925, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 849, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sh.py", line 877, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1: 

  RAN: /Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg/configure --disable-everything --enable-openssl --enable-nonfree --enable-protocol=https,tls_openssl --enable-parser=aac,ac3,h261,h264,mpegaudio,mpeg4video,mpegvideo,vc1 --enable-decoder=aac,h264,mpeg4,mpegvideo --enable-muxer=h264,mov,mp4,mpeg2video --enable-demuxer=aac,h264,m4v,mov,mpegvideo,vc1 --disable-symver --disable-programs --disable-doc --enable-filter=aresample,resample,crop,adelay,volume,scale --enable-protocol=file,http,hls --enable-small --enable-hwaccels --enable-gpl --enable-pic --disable-static --disable-debug --enable-shared --target-os=android --enable-cross-compile --cross-prefix=armv7a-linux-androideabi21- --arch=arm --strip=arm-linux-androideabi-strip --sysroot=/Users/maithreyasitaraman/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64/sysroot --enable-neon --prefix=/Users/maithreyasitaraman/Downloads/2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/ffmpeg/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/ffmpeg

  STDOUT:
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
tput: No value for $TERM and no -T specified
armv7a-linux-androideabi21-clang is unable to create an executable file.
C compiler test failed.

If you think configure made a mistake, make sure you are using the latest
version from Git.  If the latest version fails, report the problem to the
ffmpeg-user@ffmpeg.org mailing list or IRC #ffmpeg on irc.freenode.net.
Include the log file "ffbuild/config.log" produced by configure as this will help
solve the problem.


  STDERR:
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to build a project in Kivy for android for and faced similar issue where in the sound play was working fine on Laptop but not on Android device.

As i could see from your buildspec file it does not include the below requirement of ffpyplayer. Try to include this one and rebuild again clean. Hopefully it should resolve your issue

requirements = python3,kivy,ffpyplayer

Comment: This might the problem. However, my buildozer fails to compile when I add this requirement, and I am currently trying to figure out why. It might be some kind of incompatibility of old/new versions. I'll get back to you when I can get buildozer to compile.

Comment: clean up the hidden folders that get created and try to do a fresh build. Ref of my project spec - https://github.com/novicejava1/python/blob/master/kivy/KivyTesting/KivyScreen/buildozer.spec

Comment: When I add ffpyplayer or ffmpeg in the requirements, buildozer fails to compile :( - and I have tried a lot of things to get it to not fail, including reinstalling buildozer and its dependencies (and of course cleaning hidden files) - but to no avail. Do you by any chance have any guess as to what goes wrong? When you first compiled buildozer with the requirements, did the compilation fail for you too?

Comment: I was able to deploy and run you sound app on Android device and it works fine.ref - https://github.com/novicejava1/python/tree/master/kivy/soundtest for build spec. If you placed you .wav file in the same directory as .py and .kv file you need to update the build spec line to include it while it builds

Comment: ref - https://novicejava1.blogspot.com/2020/06/how-to-build-and-deploy-python-kivy.html if any buildozer specific issue with dependencies and unable to build any apk itself

Comment: I downloaded all the github files, and ran it verbatim. As expected, it works perfectly on laptop. When I try to build the apk, it is unable to build and I still get the same error: "# Command failed: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,ffpyplayer --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/Users/.../2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21"

Comment: (and with regard to dependencies, all dependencies here https://buildozer.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#targeting-android have been installed. ffplayer also has been installed. python-for-android has already been installed too. I in fact reinstalled all, to make sure they were installed in the right place and not installed for the old python2 accidentally). So, I really do not understand what is going wrong :( - but from the error message it seems that ffmpeg is causing some problem.

Comment: ok, run in debug mode to capture the logs to check further "buildozer -v android debug deploy run logcat > log.txt". May be someone can highlight the cause from the log

Comment: Good idea; I have posted the log in the EDIT below the answer. Thank you!

Comment: I managed to get it to work! Actually, the other answer put me across the final stretch, and so I gave the bounty to him. But your answer was incredibly helpful, hit the nail on the head, and I could not leave you emptyhanded :) - so I accepted your answer. That way, I distributed the reputation across the 2 answers. Thank you once again!

Answer (score 2):

There should be permission needed to play sound. The list of permissions in Android can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission). Then you will need to specify that permission in the buildozer.spec file and also in the code:

```
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission
request_permissions([Permission.the_permission_you_want])
```

**Updated Buildozer Spec File:**

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = SoundTest

# (str) Package name
package.name = soundtest

# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.soundtest

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas,wav

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,python-for-android

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/icon.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = landscape

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET, WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

**Updated Python Code:**

```
import kivy

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.graphics import Color
from kivy.core.audio import SoundLoader
from android.permissions import request_permissions, Permission

request_permissions([Permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE])

__version__ = '0.1'

class SoundTestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        self.load_kv('soundtest.kv')
        return SoundTestWidget()

class SoundTestWidget(Widget):
    def playsound(self):
        sound = SoundLoader.load('testmusic.wav')
        sound.play()

SoundTestApp().run()
```

**Commands To Run Before Compiling:**

```
buildozer android clean
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, I would take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39821017/simple-kivy-app-press-button-to-play-mp3-doesnt-work-on-android-device).

Comment: Either way, I would look at that post as it is exactly what you would like it to do :)

Comment: Since I manually turned on permissions on my android device, does this not address your suggestion? Would I be correct in assuming that with the above code inserted I cannot run the program on my laptop? (" ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'android' "). Note further: the link in your comment does not provide a solution for this issue, unfortunately.

Comment: You would need to add `python-for-android` to your requirements in buildozer. Then, add that line of code that I showed above.

Comment: Replace `the_permission_you_want` with the permission found [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission) for playing audio. Then that should solve your issue :)

Comment: Another important thing to note is to make sure the audio file format (`mp3`, `wav`, etc.) is compiled in your application with this line in the buildozer.spec file.
`# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts`

Comment: When I add python-for-android in the requirements, buildozer fails to compile :( - and I have tried a lot of things to get it to not fail, including reinstalling buildozer and its dependencies (and of course cleaning hidden files) - but to no avail. Do you by any chance have any guess as to what goes wrong?

Comment: Sure! I have posted the log in the EDIT below the answer. The error message I recieved was:  "# Command failed: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin/python3 -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy,ffpyplayer --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/Users/.../2_Sound_Test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21". Thank you!

Comment: Are you running this on the latest version of Ubuntu?

Comment: I am on mac OS, but yes my OS is pretty up to date

Comment: I managed to get it to work! Actually, your answer put me across the final stretch, and so I gave the bounty to you. sb9's answer was incredibly helpful and hit the nail on the head, so I accepted his answer and gave you the bounty. That way, I distributed the reputation across the 2 answers, since it was a combination of the answers which enabled me to understand and solve the problem. I wanted to really thank you - now the sound works on my android device - the bounty I gave you was well deserved! Take care buddy :).

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help out!

Comment: @MaithreyaSitaraman, can you actually explain what you did to solve your issue? I'm not entirely sure what "this answer put me across the final stretch means", how did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

There may be quite a few reasons for this. First of all, I don't see anything wrong with the code so there must be a problem with the target system. I suggest that you check whether any access (to speaker) is blocked by antivirus software.......This has happened repeatedly with me in the past, checking the app permissions is probably the only solution.

Comment: Thank you! I do not think this is the problem, since I do not have any external antivirus installed. However, if the other methods do not work I will surely do some more due diligence to see whether this is the problem w.r.t the inbuilt security. I will get back to you in a couple of days.